# networkX create topolohy

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, topology

how can I create a graph, which contains two rings of k/2 neurons each and both rings should be connected by a bridge.

```
G = nx.generators.lattice.grid_2d_graph(k, 1, periodic=True)
G = nx.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G)
```

does not work. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Should it be exactly one bridge? what decides which nodes should be connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
G1 = nx.generators.lattice.grid_2d_graph(k/2, 1, periodic=True)
G1 = nx.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G1)
G2 = nx.generators.lattice.grid_2d_graph(k/2, 1, periodic=True)
G2 = nx.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G2)
G =  nx.union(G1, G2, rename=('g1-', 'g2-'))
G.add_edge('g1-0', 'g2-0')
```

Comment: Can you please give more information about why your answer solves the posters questions?

Comment: Instead of creating one graph with k vertices create two graphs with k/2 vertices and then add an edge between two vertices to create the required topology.